# How to loop through each value from CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am working only on queries for now and not TSQL. So i want to fetch my results thru query.

I want to display first monday of every month. I have comeup with a query to find the dates of every month in tht year thru CTE. (So my CTE gives 12 dates).

Now , i want to check each date and get the nearest monday. That would be my first monday of that month.

I am unable to go thru each date in my query.

How can i work on this result set?

Thanks

```
with
Wk_num
as

(select 1 as n

union all

select n=n+1 
from wk_num
where n <12)


select dateadd(month,n,getdate()) from wk_num
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If any of these answers solve your problem. Then accept it as an answer, by clicking on the checkmark beside it to toggle it from greyed out to fill in. @malavika

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple method use modulo arithmetic:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(date, '2019-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from cte
      where dateadd(month, 1, dte) < '2020-01-01'
     )
select dte, 
       dateadd(day, (9 - datepart(weekday, dte)) % 7, dte) as first_monday
from cte;
```

This assumes that the weekday numbers starts with `1` on Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to actually get the first day of each month and the first Monday of each month (This doesn't use any complex functions just simple date functions):

```
with Wk_num as
(select 1 as n
union all
select n=n+1 from wk_num where n <12)
select  dateadd(month,n,datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),1)) as FirstDay,
        dateadd(day,iif(9-datepart(dw,dateadd(month,n,datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),1)))>7,2-datepart(dw,dateadd(month,n,datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),1))),9-datepart(dw,dateadd(month,n,datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),1)))),dateadd(month,n,datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()),1))) as FirstMonday
from wk_num
```